# How many traitors and detectives are there?

Tags: garrys-mod, trouble-in-terrorist-town

So I know how much traitors and detectives are there is decided by the number of players on the server. But how big is the share of players that are traitors or detectives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the convars and defaults listed [here](http://ttt.badking.net/config-and-commands/convars#TOC-Traitor-and-Detective-counts),  25% (rounded down, min 1) of players will be traitor, and 13% (rounded down) will be detective. Note that both settings are adjustable for servers and there are also settings (listed on the page linked) for setting a max for both.

> ttt_traitor_pct (def. 0.25): Percentage of total players that will be
>   a traitor. The number of players will be multiplied by this number,
>   and then rounded down. If the result is less than 1 or more than the
>   player count, it is clamped to those values.
>
> ttt_detective_pct (def. 0.13): Percentage of total players that will
>   be a detective (detective innocent). Handled similar to traitor_pct
>   (rounded down etc).
>
> ttt_detective_min_players (def. 10): Minimum number of players before
>   detectives enter play. At lower playercounts it will be purely normal
>   innocents vs traitors, at higher ones some innocents will be
>   detective.